# Insert lists in a list Scheme

Tags: list, lambda, scheme

I want to create a list of numbers binaries and i did a function to make binaries (lists of 1 and 0) but when i try introduce these lists to a list something goes wrong.

```scm
(define make (lambda (bin s)
  (if (= s 0)
      (display bin)
      (make (cons (random 2) bin) (- s 1)))))

(define insert (lambda (ls a)
   (if (= a 0)
      (display ls)
      (insert (cons make ls) (- a 1)))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your procedure is building a list as output, then don't `display` it in the base case, that messes with the recursion. Also, you're not properly invoking `make`, you're supposed to pass two arguments to it. And `insert` is not inserting an element anywhere... let's start over, shall we?

```
(define make
  (lambda (bin s)
    (if (= s 0)
        bin
        (make (cons (random 2) bin) (- s 1)))))

(make '() 5)
=> '(1 0 0 1 1)

(define insert
  (lambda (ls e a)
    (if (= a 0)
        (cons e ls)
        (cons (car ls)
              (insert (cdr ls) e (- a 1))))))

(insert '(1 2 4) 3 2)
=> '(1 2 3 4)
```